# Paste numerical expression to OS X Calculator

Tags: macos, mac

Given a numerical expression, for example:

```
1 + 2
```

If I paste it to Windows calculator (in scientific mode), I got the expected calculation:

```
3
```

However, pasting it to Mac OS X Calculator (tried in Mountain Lion, Mavericks, Yosemite), the numeric expression is not calculated. Instead, it strips out the operators and simply pastes the numbers:

```
12
```

My workaround is to paste it to Spotlight instead, and it calculates nicely.

How to paste the the numerical expression to Mac Calculator so that it performs the calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your workaround is the solution, unless Yosemite will do anything different, calculator itself doesn't appear to be that smart when pasting.

1-(2*3)+4 actually pastes 1 into calculator, so it's not even stripping the operators properly.
Spotlight gives the correct answer.